# How to display image when any link is shared on Facebook, WhatsApp or any platform in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, image, hyperlink, meta-tags

I am very new in reactjs. when I share a link it should display the image. I tried with updating of meta tag using react-meta-tags dependency but did not work however it is updating document title but not work for the image. I tried with react-document-meta but did not work.
Please help me
[image: Please check image for your reference]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import MetaTags from "react-meta-tags";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wx-1120px border-box pxl-10px">
      <MetaTags>
        <title>Page 1</title>
        <meta
          id="meta-description"
          name="description"
          content="Some description."
        />
        <meta id="og-title" property="og:title" content="MyApp" />
        <meta
          id="og-image"
          property="og:image"
          content="https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg"
        />
      </MetaTags>
      <h3 className="wx-100precent fsx-48px din-bo alText-center mxb-15px">
        Test Title{" "}
      </h3>
      <img
        src="https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg"
        alt="test"
        height="300"
        width="300"
      />
      <p className="alText-center din-re fsx-14px color-HEX666666 mxb-30px">
        Published by - Test User | 8 minute read
      </p>

      <style jsx>{`
        .word-wrap {
          word-wrap: break-word;
          text-align: justify;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp does not support images with size greater than 300kB.

Add this meta tag to show image (less than 300kB) in whatsApp

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url_image">
```

Comment: Hello Zohaib, Image size is 76kb only.

Comment: what's image extension ?

Comment: .jpg
link of image: https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg

Comment: sandbox editor link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-bhaskara-vle0i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It's dimentions are too big. it should be 300x200 or 300x300

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211643/discussion-between-zohaib-ijaz-and-vicky-kumar).